# Why CreateFileMappingA and CreateFileA uses different return values on error?

Tags: c++, windows

Both CreateFileMappingA and CreateFileA returns HANDLE type, but [CreateFileMappingA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) returns NULL on error, and [CreateFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE instead.

I'm wondering why the API is designed like that, why won't those APIs both use NULL or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE?

Comment: The world is not a perfect place.  Even Microsoft make mistakes :)

Comment: [Why are HANDLE return values so inconsistent?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Raymond Chen in [Why are HANDLE return values so inconsistent?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443):

> Why are the return values so inconsistent?
>
> The reasons, as you may suspect, are historical.
>
> The values were chosen to be compatible with 16-bit Windows